# ng-view unable to display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

```
-----index.html-------
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-
route.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="aboutController.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="aboutController">
        <h1>About Page</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>

<button ng-click="go()">Submit</button>

<div ng-view></div>

</div>
</html>


----main.js--------

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/go", {
        templateUrl : "sample.html"
    });
});

----aboutController.js---------

     var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

     app.controller('aboutController', function($scope,$http,$location) {
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.message="Home Page";


    $scope.go= function(){
    $http.get('content.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.obj = data;
        $location.path("/go");
    });
    }

     });

------sample.html--------
<h1>Sample Page</h1>
```

I am trying to use angular routing in this test application. Can you tell what am I doing wrong here? When I click on the submit button, location in the address bar changes to "http://localhost:8080/index.html#/go" but I don't see the contents of "sample.html" in ng-view.

Comment: It would be much easier to find a reason on this behavior when you provide a Plunker.

Comment: There are lot of issues with your code

Comment: @Sajeetharan what are those issues?

Comment: what do you want to do? you want to load about page when click on button go?

Comment: @Sajeetharan no. First I run index.html(about page) which has a ng-view in it. When I click on the button, I want the contents of the sample.html to be displayed inside the ng-view of index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your module for your app twice so it is overwriting the first configuration. Remove the second declaration: `var app = angular.module("myApp", []);`

Heres your code working (I've remove the GET request and substituted template url with template for demonstrative purposes):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/go", {
      template: "<h1>Sample Page</h1>"
    });
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.message = "Home Page";


  $scope.go = function() {
    $location.path("/go");
  }

});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-
route.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="aboutController.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="aboutController">
  <h1>About Page</h1>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>

  <button ng-click="go()">Submit</button>

  <div ng-view></div>

</div>

</html>
```